# Fastest Way to fill values of a dataframe using .loc from another multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe  **df1**:

```
key1    key2   val
1       100     
2       500   
4       400
```

Also i have a multi-indexed dataframe  **df2**:

```
       c
a  b     
1 100  a
2 200  b
3 300  j
4 400  e
5 500  t
```

i want to fill the column `val` of my df1 from the multi-indexed dataframe **df2**

I tried:

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        data = df2.loc([row['key1'],row['key2'])
        df1.loc[(df1.key1 == row['key1']) & (df1.key2 == row['key2']), 'val'] = data
    except:
        pass
```

finally, my df1 should look like:

```
key1    key2   val
1       100     a
2       500   
4       400     e
```

But my main concerns is that the actual length of df2(multi-indexed df) will be around 60-70 thousand rows.

The length of df1 will be hardly 10 rows.
(and i want to repeat this process taking df1 containing other data)

SO does this .loc using for loop work? Is it the fastest?

Or using .apply will be faster?

I want this iteration to be the fastest.

Any leads on **running this in the fastest way possible**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid `loops`s - `iterrows` and `apply` (loops under hood), better are vectorized solutions.

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with parameter `on`:

```
#for improve performance sort index and columns
df2 = df2.sort_index()
df1 = df1.sort_values(['key1','key2'])

df = df1.join(df2, on=['key1','key2'])
print (df)
   key1  key2  val    c
0     1   100  NaN    a
1     2   500  NaN  NaN
2     4   400  NaN    e
```

EDIT:

Another aproach is join `MultiIndex` and columns values and use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2.index = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df2.index]
print (df2)
       c
1_100  a
2_200  b
3_300  j
4_400  e
5_500  t

df1['joined'] = df1['key1'].astype(str) + '_' + df1['key2'].astype(str)
print (df1)
   key1  key2  val joined
0     1   100  NaN  1_100
1     2   500  NaN  2_500
2     4   400  NaN  4_400

df1['col'] = df1['joined'].map(df2['c'])
print (df1)
   key1  key2  val joined  col
0     1   100  NaN  1_100    a
1     2   500  NaN  2_500  NaN
2     4   400  NaN  4_400    e
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10000, size=(N, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(['a','b']).set_index(['a','b'])
print (df2.head())
              c
a    b         
3582 1346  5218
7763 9785  7382
5857 96    6257
6782 4143  4169
5664 942   6368

df1 = df2.iloc[np.random.randint(N, size=10)].reset_index()
df1.columns = ['key1','key2','val']
print (df1)
   key1  key2   val
0  5157  9207   283
1  6452  6474  7092
2  1264  5009  5123
3    86  7225  1025
4  7787  5134   637
5  9406  6119  8719
6  7479  1493  1525
7  4098  7248  7618
8  9921  7925  8547
9  2320   764  1564
```

1.Join with unsorted `MultiIndex`, columns:

```
In [42]: %timeit df1.join(df2, on=['key1','key2'])
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
```

2.Then first sort and then join (sorting is not used in timings):

```
df2 = df2.sort_index()

In [44]: %timeit df1.join(df2, on=['key1','key2'])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop
```

3.`map` solution, also join `MultiIndex` is not count in timings, if still same data only run once:

```
df2.index = ['{}_{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df2.index]
df1['joined'] = df1['key1'].astype(str) + '_' + df1['key2'].astype(str)

In [51]: %timeit df1['col'] = df1['joined'].map(df2['c'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 371 µs per loop
```

---

```
In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: df1['joined'] = df1['key1'].astype(str) + '_' + df1['key2'].astype(str)
    ...: df1['col'] = df1['joined'].map(df2['c'])
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 ms per loop
```

Comment: Joining df1(very smaller df) with df2(very bigger in size) will cause any performance issues? Also. replace Na by 0 also can be done, right?

Comment: @Shubham - I think `join` is better as loops solutions, for replace `NaN`s to `0` use `df['c'] = df['c'].fillna(0)`

Comment: :) good , Just out of curiosity of all the three methods, which is the fastest?

Comment: Thanks , even i'm running %timeit on the pieces :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a `fill value` question, but a `filter index` question. Try below:

```
df1 = df1.set_index(["key1", "key2"])
result = df2.loc[df1.index, :].reset_index()
```

If you want to remain the original columns:

```
result.columns=["key1", "key2", "val"]
```